# How to delete a number when formatting a double

Tags: java, formatting, double

So I have a percentage in the form of 0.xx% and I want to get rid of the 0.

I've tried so many ways, and I've looked on StackOverflow but nothing seems to do the trick (or I keep getting it wrong)

The ways I tried are the following

```
String.format("%2d", (int) data);
String.format("%0$.2f", data);
```

How can I get 0.01% to simply %1 or 0.10 to simply 10% using String.format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply multiply `data` by 100.

```
String.format("%2d", (int) (data * 100));
String.format("%0$.2f", data * 100);
```